# How to create user groups/chatrooms in tcp sockets

Tags: java, sockets, chat

I have a tcp chat server in which I can handle multiple clients using threads. At first I started with a single room (a client message received by server will be broadcasted to other clients).

Now I am handling 5 rooms in each thread with their own set of global maps with listeners(socket.getoutputstream) as key and username as value. But it is not the way I want. I did not used room threads because its difficult to pass different types of data to them while they are running. In future maybe I will expand rooms but I can't figure it out how it should be done. Code looks like this:

```
// dummy part of clientthread 
public void room1(BufferedReader in, PrintWriter out,String username) { 
    room1map.put(out, username); 
    while(true){
        String message = in.readline;
        if(message==null){ 
            room1map.remove(out) 
            return;
        } 
        for(PrintWriter writer : room1map.keySet()){ 
            writer.println(username + ": " + message)
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to separate your logic from threads. You need to abstract the whole room-idea from the communication layer. That said, you first need to come up with a decent protocol that can handle your requirements ( i.e. represent messages targeting a specific room ).

Comment: Say one user is in 3 rooms - you wouldn't want him to establish 3 TCP connections to your server, do you? You would want the comm protocol to include some sort of room identifier and handle that on a higher layer than network.

Comment: Look at dummy client thread, when a user enters room1 i simply pass it to room 1.that way server can handle which room users belongs to. The question is how can i create say 100 rooms. 5 rooms are ok but 100, I definetly not gonna write that much code. How can i combine code into one single roomhandler.